# What is the exact font name, size and color of the header and footers for tableviews in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I'm trying to figure out the exact font name, size and color of the header and footers for tableviews. I wish apple provided some default color, font, size, etc. for this. I've messed around a bit and got the font size of 12 and the name to be Helvitica Neue, but the color is much more difficult to find out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a screenshot and use a color picker.

Comment: Use Debug View Hierarchy... You can inspect all properties of the tableview and its headers, footers, etc.

Comment: I'm confused on why someone down voted my question. Could someone please explain so that I can learn from my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement willDisplayFooterView/willDisplayHeaderView and inspect the label.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        let h = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        print(h.textLabel?.font) //the font
        print(h.textLabel?.textColor) //the color
    }
```

Which prints

UICTFont: 0x7fc5035114e0> **font-family: ".SFUIText-Semibold"; font-weight: bold;** font-style: normal; **font-size: 17.00pt**

UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace **r:0.137255 g:0.137255 b:0.137255 a:1**

i.e UIColor.darkText

Comment: Do you know why someone would have down voted my question?

Comment: a reviewer judged it not technical enough